# How to access Passport 'done' function from rest of the code while authenticating using passport.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I am trying to implement authentication in my API using passport.js with passport_jwt strategy. the code is attached below

```js
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy,
    ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const opts = {}
const User = require('../models/user_model')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')

module.exports = function(passport) {
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
    opts.secretOrKey = process.env.JWT_SECRET;

    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
        User.findById(jwt_payload._id, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err, false);
            }
            if (user) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false);
            }
        });
    }));
}
```

here I have passed the user on the **done** function on successful authentication. For my post routes I used **passport.authenticate** as a route middleware like below.

```js
app.use('/api/v1/posts', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session : false }), postRoutes)
```

Now the question is how can I access the user, previously sent on the done function, while creating the post routes? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access **user** in your **postRoutes** method as code below:

```
exports.postRoutes = async (req, res) => {
    console.log('req.user =====>', req.user);
    res.status(200).send({ user: req.user })
};
```